# Put all network operations inside single thread

Tags: android

I have a chat app and I have to use network so I have to use another thread for network operations.My problem is starting here.I have to connect with this line to my server:

```
connection=new XMPPTCPConnection(configuration);
connection.connect();
chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
```

I am using new thread for this operations.But when user wants to send a message I have to use `chatManager` variable in message sender method.But I set this variable inside a thread so I can't access from another thread.How can I resolve this problem ? I am sending new message with these lines:

```
Chat chat=chatManager.createChat(to,messageListener);
chat.sendMessage(message);
```

I think,I have to put all network operations inside one thread but how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a AsyncTask to make a connection and send the data back to your Activity when it's over, launch your AsyncTask whenever you want to do heavy work (few seconds).

Comment: Time to hit [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: Yes, it does. You could use a Handler too, but AsyncTask is Google's predilection.

Comment: If I hit the send message for 10 times,will system fire 10 threads ?

Comment: I think I have to use intentservice for this operation

Comment: You are right a Service will do the trick. Don't forget to post your answer, who knows it'll help someone.